# avoid cyclomatic complexity in switch statements(useReducer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

it is a common pattern to use the switch statement with `useReducer` hook to handle complex states, but the [complexity](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/complexity) rule thrown error if the number of cases is too high. what are the alternatives to refactor this code to satisfy this rule?

```js
export type SearchState = {
  search: string;
  markets: Market[];
};

type SearchAction =
  | { type: SearchActionKind.UpdateSearch; search: string }
  | { type: SearchActionKind.LoadInitialMarkets; markets: Market[] };

const searchReducer = (prevState: SearchState, action: SearchAction): SearchState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UpdateSearch:
      return { ...prevState, search: action.search };

    case LoadInitialMarkets:
      return { ...prevState, markets: action.markets };

    // ... many other cases

    default:
      return prevState;
  }
};
```

Comment: Disable the unhelpful rule, either locally or globally.

Comment: currently in the project I am working on does not allow to disable eslint rules, there are local and github actions that do not allow this.

Comment: Absolute React noob here, and a complete tangent, but shouldn't `prevState` be cloned in the `default` case too (eg `return { ...prevState}`) to maintain the illusion of immutability?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a map to reduce the switch statement?

```
const map = {};
map[UpdateSearch] = 'search';
map[LoadInitialMarkets] = 'markets';

if (map.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {

  const key = map[action.type];
  const result = { ...prevState };
  result[key] = action[key];

  return result;
}

switch (action.type) {

    // ... the complicated cases

    default:
      return prevState;

}
```

Comment: What is the idea to put switch inside else statement? is not clear to me

Comment: @CristianFlórez, good point. We can remove the return statement.

Comment: can you explain to me in a more extensive way why I would need the switch? the idea is to remove the switch as this causes problems with the complexity rule.

Comment: @CristianFlórez If all of your switch cases are simple, you can remove the `switch` statement. It's just if you have 2-3 complicated switch cases, you may find a `switch` statement still useful.